# Efficiently compare two sets in Python

Tags: python, performance, set

I have two large integer sets, `set1` and `set2`. Which one of the below is more efficient?

Example:

```py
if(set1 == set2)
```

or

```py
if(len(set1)==len(set2))
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The two statements are completely different from each other.

`if(set1==set2)` compares for equality of each element in both the sets, and evaluates to true if and only if both the sets are exactly same.

Whereas `if(len(set1)==len(set2))` compares only the length of both the sets.
Even if you have two sets with same length there may be cases when they are not the same. For eg consider this:

> set1: [1, 3, 6, 29, 31]
>
> set2: [1, 3, 7, 10, 15]

Though the sets have the same length they are not the same.

You could do this to save on time.

```
if len(set1) == len(set2):
    if set1 == set2:
        //TODO when sets are equal
    else
        //TODO when sets are not equal.
else
    //TODO when sets are not equal
```

Comment: @user30478 I agree. Worse, if this answer addresses the correctness part, it is misleading about the efficiency part .... see answer below.

Answer (score 21):

As Nikhil Wagh already explained, in the original question there was a confusion between comparing the length of a set and checking the equality of two sets. I just want to add that simple `s1 == s2` is enough and is efficient, because  __eq__() (and its oppsite __ne__()) method already performs this optimization. It first checks if the sets have the same length, then it checks if the sets have the same hash, and only then it performs `set_issubset` check.

You can find the implementation of set equality check in function `set_richcompare()` in file `setobject.c`. You don't need to be an expect in C to understand the algorithm - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c

Comment: How would this compare to taking the intersection of the sets? (Let's assume we have bias as to which one would be complete (ex: has 10 items) and which may be incomplete (ex: may have 9 or 10 items).